# Rotation Axis trouble

Tags: axis

so weird issue, when I rotate the object using the gizmo, the object rotates fine. But when adjust the rotation in the transform panel, the rotation is all wrong. Any clue why this might happen? I've tried to fix it using copy rotation constraint but that didn't work. Please see gif and image for help ^^
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgW0d.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object's axis is probably not aligned with the world's axis any more, you must apply the rotation: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*

Comment: Thanks so much, can't believe I forgot that. Worked like a charm ^^